# Retrieving a particular column value from multiple data rows PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, select, limit, between

I trying to put a query together which echo/prints one particular column value from within the table, but within a particular time frame but I'm not having much luck. From the Query below, Im trying to get the '267' in the targets_id=1 row under the targets_set column to echo/print. I get the error message **"mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource "**. How do I get it to echo?

```
<?php
$dealer = $_SESSION['sp_dealer_code'];
require_once ('/database.php');
$result = mysql_query("SELECT targets_set FROM targets WHERE targets_nmc='F80', sp_dealer_code=$dealer AND `targets_date`
BETWEEN '2014-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-01-31 23:59:59' LIMIT 1");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $row['targets_set'];
?>
```

The Database table **'targets'** and some sample data

```
targets_id  | sp_dealer_code | targets_nmc  | targets_set  | targets_actual | targets_date
1           | 1234           | F80          |  267         | 270            | 2014-01-01 01:00:00
2           | 1234           | F8R          |  350         | 300            | 2014-02-01 01:00:00
3           | 4567           | F80          |  210         | 200            | 2014-03-01 01:00:00
4           | 4567           | F8R          |  267         | 260            | 2014-01-01 01:00:00
```

Comment: Its good practice to run your query in the CLI (or GUI) and check for  errors. You could also check for errors in your PHP code. Probably you have a SQL error. http://php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is off. `WHERE A, B AND C` is not valid MySQL; rather, it should be `WHERE A AND B AND C`:

```
SELECT targets_set
FROM targets
WHERE 
    targets_nmc='F80' 
    AND sp_dealer_code=$dealer 
    AND `targets_date` BETWEEN '2014-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-01-31 23:59:59'
LIMIT 1
```

When the statement is executed, no result set is given back. That's why you get that error message when you try to fetch the result as an associative array.